# Why jexl calc arithmetic wrong

Tags: java, jexl

I use [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/) library to compute math expression with different arguments (for example y=2x+a^2-4*a*x where (x=1&a=3), (x=5&a=-15), etc). It works good on simple expressions, but when I start to use more hard expressions - it doesn't work. Here is code working well:

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
Expression func = jexl.createExpression("x1+x2");
MapContext mc = new MapContext();
mc.set("x1", 2);
mc.set("x2", 1);
System.out.println(func.evaluate(mc)); // prints "3" - GOOD ANSWER!
```

but this one print wrong answer:

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
Expression func = jexl.createExpression("(x1-2)^4+(x1-2*x2)^2");
MapContext mc = new MapContext();
mc.set("x1", 2);
mc.set("x2", 1);
System.out.println(func.evaluate(mc)); // prints "6" - WRONG ANSWER!
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is bitwise xor, so 6 is the expected answer. See [JEXL syntax](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/reference/syntax.html) for details.

Comment: You are right! Thx! So, how can I implement Math.pow() in JEXL? Or I should use another lib for my purposes?

Comment: @dizpers I've never used JEXL myself, so I cannot help you there. I'd suggest to look for examples on the internet. They (the JEXL community) also have mailing lists where you might get more answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like that:

```
   Map<String, Object> functions=new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
   // creating namespace for function eg. 'math' will be treated as Math.class
   functions.put( "math",Math.class);
   JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
   //setting custom functions
   jexl.setFunctions( functions);
   // in expression 'pow' is a function name from 'math' wich is Math.class
   Expression expression = jexl.createExpression( "math:pow(2,3)" );   
   expression.evaluate(new MapContext());
```